# How to convert Grayscale IplImage to Bitmap in JavaCV for Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, javacv, grayscale

I am working on a Android app which will get a `Bitmap` from `ImageView`. Convert this `Bitmap` to JavaCV`IplImage` and then to grayscale as below:

```
IplImage image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());
IplImage _3image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
IplImage _1image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(image, _3image, CV_BGRA2BGR);
cvCvtColor(_3image, _1image, CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

However I get a `RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels` when I do this

```
Bitmap x = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);            
x.copyPixelsFromBuffer(_1image.getByteBuffer());
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about if you call `x.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.getByteBuffer())`?

Comment: @SamuelAudet yes `x.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.getByteBuffer())` works fine.

Comment: So call `cvCvtColor(_1image, image, CV_GRAY2RGBA)` before that and you're done

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Hi,Samuel still I'm getting error with this. I need your help ASAP.

Comment: @Jai That just means your `IplImage` is too small: Make it bigger.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Let me tell you briefly what I'm doing. I'm using javaCV to record video. I'm taking byte[] at onPreviewFrames. Now I'm going to assign that byte data to IPLImage by this code :

yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

this yuvIplimage is created with following parameters : yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight,
     opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Now problem is when I'm going to create bitmap with Bitmap.Config.RGB_565..bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer()); working fine.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : But if I take bitmap with Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888..it is not able to copyPixelsFromButter.

Comment: @Jai ARGB: That requires 4 channels.

Comment: @SamuelAudet yup. I have tried to provide 4 channels. But if I provide 4 channels it giving me bad video. you can checkout image of video by this URL : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TfogY48CpDbWlCUkJVRjZCbUtDRmQxc3dxQjJEazFUT2Jz/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Have you checked above image? Got my issue?

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Sorry above link will need you login. I have uploaded on other place. Kindly checkout image by this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzrk5tecb00na09/Screenshot_2014-04-17-18-53-31.png

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Please help me ASAP by checking this image. Its looks like 4 parts of same screen showing in video

Comment: @Jai It looks like you're trying to load a grayscale image into a color image: That won't work. You need an "ARGB" image ([actually RGBA](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60644)) for Android.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Hi ,i think u r right. but not exactly able to understand. Can you help me by some snippet code? Also I have posted my question over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149867/4-channel-iplimage-javacv-to-android-bitmap

Comment: @SamuelAudet : I have already try to convert it using cVCvtColor kindly check question that I have posted.

Comment: @SamuelAudet : I have checked again n again, even after converting to RGBA. Should it be any device specific issue? I'm checking with my nexus 4. :( Have you checked my question? I need your help urgently buddy!!

Comment: @SamuelAudet : hey, have you got my problem? Still I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @SamuelAudet : waiting buddy :)

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Help needed pls..

Comment: @SamuelAudet : Hey, I really need your help please. Can you tell me after checking that question? I have userd CvCvtColor to change it to the ARGB, then y still I'm not able to get output? Still I'm doing any mistake in sequence?